# How to split the DOM from an existing page across multiple browser windows?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I’d like to be able to take the DOM structure from an existing page and then separate certain elements across different browser windows. When doing so, I’d like to retain the same session across each of these browser windows. Is this possible? And if so, how would one go about doing this?

To give more clarity, here’s an example of how this would be used:

1) I login to a site and create the session.

2) The site has various widgets on the page. Some of the widgets I need to use, some I do not. Instead of hiding the ones I don’t need via CSS, I’d rather extract the ones I do need into separate windows. Then I could arrange those individual widget windows across my desktop as much as I want.

Any way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: Why you have to do that? Web pages is not desktop application.
You can still do that with window.open api, Open a pop up an control it but will be very hard to control em all

Comment: is it regarding web application or desktop application ?

Comment: This would be for a web application. I'd be willing to also use Electron to make the website a desktop app and then add this window splitting functionality.

Comment: You want to build a site like those or when you browser any site them could do it?

Answer (score 6):

> I’d like to retain the same session across each of these browser windows.

Sessions are not maintained by the DOM. They exist in cookies and maybe javascript state.

> I’d like to be able to take the DOM structure from an existing page and then separate certain elements across different browser windows.

There are two options, DOM nodes can be directly transplanted from one document to via [adoptNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/adoptNode) but that requires direct access between the different javascript global contexts, which is only available via frames or [window.opener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/opener), i.e. when one window directly spawned the other. Note that this just moves DOM nodes, not any state or listeners associated with them.

The alternative is serializing them to HTML or XML and sending the serialized form to another window via various communication mechanisms such as `postMessage` or channels.

Since you say *widgets* I guess there is some javascript associated with them. That javascript will have to be rewritten to communicate across window boundaries in a similar fashion as you move the DOM nodes themselves across window boundaries.

If your frontend is implemented as MVC or similar patterns you should just move the model to a different window and rematerialize the view instead of moving the dom directly.

Answer (score 0):

If you want display different elements among some page, maybe you could try to use **localStorage** to share message with different tabs on one browser. When a page is opened set an identity for it and save to localStorage, and every page listen to the change of localStorage. Then you could control what will be displayed on one window by set localStorage to share settings.

But your second part of example may not a good idea because a browser window have many same part, them can not be hide and useless and them could not be set on the top. Make a desktop app would fix this problem but in today web developer ways normally in a webpage you could move or hide some widgets. So you could think about this way or try to achieve your thoughts by above way.

Hope this can help you in some way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Multi Layout Manager for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/multi-layout-manager/ijpiffheldgmdkbaohoilabdnmeinand?hl=en). This way you can arrange your windows as you like and save them for later usage. You can use web sockets (WinRT or SignalR) to sync and communicate among windows.

Hope this helps.